# Triggering closest button on a delegated event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html repeated through my code, with a 'gobutton' class on the correct button to activate when enter is pressed:

```
<div>
  <input type="text">
  <button id="btnGO" class="gobutton">GO</button>
</div>
```

And a block of jquery code which fires correctly, but will not activate the gobutton. I'm guessing it's because the closest function isn't working due to the delegation, but I'm not sure?

```
$('body').on('keypress', 'input:text', function (e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if(key == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.gobutton').click();
    }
});
```

Comment: `.closest()` searches up in the tree. You are looking for `.siblings()` selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`button` is sibling of input element not parent, so [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) will not work as it traverses up the DOM hierarchy.

You can use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up to the common parent and then use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target the desired element.

*Use*

```
 $(this).closest('div').find('.gobutton').click();
 //$(this).next('.gobutton').click();
 //$(this).siblings('.gobutton').click();
```

You can also use [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) or [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

Comment: Thanks - this works, I've ended up using a couple of functions though as different text fields are nested in different types of container, and the gobutton is not always a sibling (sometimes in a lower SPAN). So I'm using a class of 'inp-form' for text fields within a form, and 'inp-li' when they are within a list item, etc. Not sure if there is a neater way of doing this though?

Comment: @user4893295 You can use first approach, where you traverse up to common parent and then target the button i.e.  `$(this).closest('div').find('.gobutton').click();`

Comment: Have tried that, but for some reason it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use next method here is the detail 
[.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

Example : `$(this).next('.gobutton').click();`